# Devexpress Dropdown Controls stay hidden with PopupEditForm

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, devexpress

In my ASP.Net application i using devexpress controls and bootstrap framework.

The problem is when i put combobox or dateedit into a popupeditform from the gridview, the dropdown of these controls stay hidden behind of modal popup.

My code:

```
<EditForm>
    <div style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px; width: 500px">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Expiração</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="ASPxDateEdit1" runat="server" Width="100%">
                    </dx:ASPxDateEdit>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: right; margin-top: 10px">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Guardar" Width="100px" OnClientClick="ValidarNoticia(); return false;"></asp:Button>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="Cancelar" Width="100px" OnClientClick="ClientGridView.CancelEdit(); return false;"></asp:Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

If i dont use the "bootstrap system grid" (col-sm-10) i have no problem with the common controls (dateedit or combobox).

I try to change the z-index of the control but without sucess.

Anyone has this kind of problem?

Tnks for your help and sorry for my english explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem guys. Only need to put a position static on a div with the controls.

```
<div class="col-sm-10" style="position: static;">
```